# Can't access internet inside docker windows container inside corporate proxy

Tags: docker

I need to connect to the Internet from inside a container.

Initially, the Docker daemon was not able to connect to the Internet and I was unable to run:

```
docker pull hello-world
```

I resolved this by specifying a manual proxy in the docker desktop GUI settings, under resources
Once I manually set the proxy I was able to pull the hello-world image - so I know this proxy works.

I then created a test Dockerfile to see if I could get a container to connect to the internet when building an image, and this is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903
RUN curl 'www.google.co.za'
```

and got this output:

```
PS C:\Projects\Test> docker build -t test:01 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.906GB

Step 1/2 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903

---> 66c07b0d3e85

Step 2/2 : RUN curl 'www.google.co.za'

---> Running in 99f79ea70731

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'www.google.co.za'

The command 'cmd /S /C curl 'www.google.co.za'' returned a non-zero code: 6
```

As was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766135/not-able-to-access-internet-inside-docker-windows-container/62795453#62795453) I tried adding a DNS as follows:

```
"dns": ["1.1.1.1"]
```

but got the same result as above.
I had previously had issues in Linux containers where I couldn't install packages inside the container and I had to add the following to the Dockerfile which worked:

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://myproxy:3128
ENV http_proxy http://myproxy:3128
```

I have tried doing this in my test Dockerfile and I get this result (note that this is the output without the DNS settings):

```
PS C:\Projects\Test> docker build -t test:01 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.906GB

Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903

---> 66c07b0d3e85

Step 2/4 : ENV HTTP_PROXY http://myproxy.com:3128

---> Using cache

---> d6bbca2c1984

Step 3/4 : ENV http_proxy http://myproxy.com:3128

---> Using cache

---> a22311c57c8d

Step 4/4 : RUN curl 'www.google.co.za'

---> Running in 3e3be3786b62

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   874  100   874    0     0    874      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  1189

<HTML><HEAD>

<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<FONT face="Helvetica">

<big><strong></strong></big><BR>

</FONT>

<blockquote>

<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">

<TR><TD>

<FONT face="Helvetica">

<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>

<BR>

<BR>

</FONT>

</TD></TR>

<TR><TD>

<FONT face="Helvetica">

Your requested host "'www.google.co.za'" could not be resolved by DNS.

</FONT>

</TD></TR>

<TR><TD>

<FONT face="Helvetica">

 

</FONT>

</TD></TR>

<TR><TD>

<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>

<BR>

For assistance, contact your network support team.<br><br>Your request was categorized by Blue Coat Web Filter as 'none'. <br>If you wish to question or dispute this result, please click <a href="http://sitereview.bluecoat.com/sitereview.jsp?referrer=136&url=http://'www.google.co.za'/">here</a>.

</FONT>

</TD></TR>

</TABLE>

</blockquote>

</FONT>

</BODY></HTML>

Removing intermediate container 3e3be3786b62

---> 79dcdbf32644

Successfully built 79dcdbf32644

Successfully tagged test:01
```

If I add the DNS settings back into the Docker GUI I get this output:

```
PS C:\Projects\Test> docker build -t test:01 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.906GB

Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903

---> 66c07b0d3e85

Step 2/4 : ENV HTTP_PROXY http://myproxy.com:3128

---> Running in 4ac3e6e23b5f

Removing intermediate container 4ac3e6e23b5f

---> 6bfbb6923789

Step 3/4 : ENV http_proxy http://myproxy.com:3128

---> Running in 7e7b08cef7b3

Removing intermediate container 7e7b08cef7b3

---> 4a827371e6fa

Step 4/4 : RUN curl 'www.google.co.za'

---> Running in 317a2ea37342

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: myproxy.com

The command 'cmd /S /C curl 'www.google.co.za'' returned a non-zero code: 5
```

So with the DNS settings it can't resolve the proxy and without the DNS settings it can't resolve the URL. I don't know how to proceed from here.

---

Removing the literal single quotes from my curl command was necessary but this hasn't solved my problem yet unfortunately.

I don't properly understand what setting the dns to "1.1.1.1" does but from the reading I did, it seemed I should rather specify the dns to the DNS server within my company's network.
I discovered this info with this command:

```
ipconfig -all
```

and there I saw 2 IP address listed as DNS servers under "Ethernet adapter Ethernet:", so I rather specified these 2 in the Docker Desktop GUI "Docker Engine" settings.

I then ran tests with 4 permutations as follows:

1. Set DNS in Docker Desktop + set proxy ENV in Dockerfile
2. Set DNS in Docker Desktop + no proxy set in Dockerfile
3. No DNS set in Docker Desktop + set proxy ENV in Dockerfile
4. No DNS set in Docker Desktop + no proxy set in Dockerfile

In each test I tried to run the following commands from my dockerfile during the build:

```
RUN curl www.google.co.za
RUN tracert www.google.co.za
```

Setting the DNS didn't seem to make any difference to the results.
Setting the ENV HTTP_PROXY set in the Dockerfile seemed to make a difference to the curl command. Without setting it I get the following output:

```
Failed to connect to www.google.co.za port 80: Timed out
```

With the ENV HTTP_PROXY set in the Dockerfile I get what looks like the HTML of the google.co.za site which makes it appear to be working.
But the *tracert* command shows that the request gets out of the container but doesn't get past my default gateway and it reports "Destination host unreachable".
So instead of running the *curl* command to [www.google.co.za](http://www.google.co.za) I used a banks site and here the curl command reports:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
```

and the tracert command fails.
I am guessing that when running *curl [www.google.co.za](http://www.google.co.za)*, I am getting a cached page somehow.

So I am still stuck and looking for help.

Comment: You can't traceroute when you have to access the web via a proxy. So you don't need to worry about that or even make any attempts to do so.

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable about the finer details of networking but I was under the impression that tracert could be used to see how far the request went which is why I was trying this. It looks like the request gets out of the container but not past my host's default gateway. Am I misunderstanding this result?

Comment: Even if tracert is not useful here, I am still stuck and unable to connect to the internet from within my container.

Comment: You should contact your proxy server administrator. It is possible that they have blocked access to various web sites.

Comment: I can access these websites from the host PC, but not when building the docker image. So I don't think that is the problem, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the literal single quotes from your curl command. They are being sent to the proxy server, so that it tries to find a host named `'www.google.co.za'` instead of the desirable `www.google.co.za`.

It should instead be:

```
RUN curl www.google.co.za
```